# Want to know is there a way to know in angular js 1.5 whether a page opened or loaded or not

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, frontend, web-frontend

I have tried using many events like `$routeChangeSuccess` and `$viewContentLoaded`

```
window.LOGGING_ON = true;
var loggingUrl = '/payment/op/payment/paymentPageRendering';

window.ajaxRequest = function () {
   var activexmodes=["Msxml2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"]; //activeX versions to check for in IE
   if (window.ActiveXObject){ //Test for support for ActiveXObject in IE first (as XMLHttpRequest in IE7 is broken)
    for (var i=0; i<activexmodes.length; i++){
     try {
      return new ActiveXObject(activexmodes[i]);
     }
     catch(e){
      //suppress error
     }
    }
   }
   else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
   else
    return false;
};
```

```
window.loggingPay = function(obj,ajxRequestObject,sync){ 
  var logUrl = loggingUrl;
  var async = true;
  if(!obj){
    var payLoad = "isRendered=false&pageUrl="+window.location;
  }else{
    var payLoad = "isRendered=true";
    for(key in obj){
      payLoad =  payLoad + "&"+key+"="+obj[key];
    }
    payLoad.isRendered = true;
  }  
  if(sync) 
    async = false;

  ajxRequestObject.open("POST", logUrl , async);  
  ajxRequestObject.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  ajxRequestObject.send(payLoad); 
  ajxRequestObject.onreadystatechange=function(res){
         if (ajxRequestObject.readyState==4){
          if (ajxRequestObject.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1){
              window.loggingObject = JSON.parse(ajxRequestObject.responseText).result;
              delete ajxRequestObject;

          } else {
            console.log("An error has occured making the error request");
          }
         }
    }
}
```

Finally what i did was,  i logged in index file and i again logged in the footer but i guess this is not a good solution , please suggest some solutions for this.

Got no specific errors but , i guess results could be faulty with this solution

Comment: Really not clear what exactly you are trying to accomplish or what higher level problem you are trying to solve

Comment: I am making a spa in which a page is very critical ,so we want to ensure that the page opens on every browser and every mobile , many times customers complaint that page didn't open, so how to know page didn't open on customers browsers , what was the error etc etc, so want to know does any angular event fires when template of a specific route is fully loaded or any solution other people use .

Answer (score 0):

You can try to combine different events like `$routeChangeSuccess`, `$stateChangeStart` and `$stateNotFound`.

And add logs to yours database, to see what errors & where users gets.

Inside this functions you can send all needed data.

> NOTE: State change events are deprecated, DISABLED and replaced by
>   Transition Hooks as of version 1.0 ([details](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#state-change-events))

Comment: Will this also catch errors as well like parsing error in controllers etc ?

Comment: I think it does not catch any errors it`s normal behavior of function. But with this you can understand where is the problem.